# How do I stop my snake moving into itself (python, pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d-games

this is my first game I have created using pygame, it's basically snake.

Please do not mind my hideous comments.

```
    ## William's Snake Game

import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

##Global variables
# Colours
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 155, 0)
bground = (204, 204, 0)

# Display vars.
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

# Variables
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))  ##resolution, note that this is a tuple.
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake VS Apple")  # Title at the top of the screen

icon = pygame.image.load('logoapple32x32.png')  # Loads the icon for the top left
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)  # Sets the icon for the top left

snakeHeadImg = pygame.image.load("snakeHead.png")  # Loads the image for the snake head
appleImg = pygame.image.load("apple20x20.png")  # Loads the image for the apple

appleThickness = 20  # Defines how thick apple will be. Note to self: This is changable
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Starts clocking the game, used later for FPS
blockSize = 20  # Defines how big the snake will be. Changing this will mess up collision detection.
FPS = 15  # Frames per second. Called at the bottom of script

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)  ## format: ("font", fontsize)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 40)  ##
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 80)  ##

direction = "right"  # Starting direction of snake, used in main gameLoop


##

def pauseGame():
    gameisPaused = True
    while gameisPaused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    gameisPaused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("Paused",
                          black,
                          -100,
                          size="large")
        message_to_screen("Press ESC to continue or Q to quit.",
                          black,
                          25,
                          size="small")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(5)


def text_objects(text, color, size):  # Function to render text
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_to_screen(msg, color, y_displace=0, size="medium"):  # Function to blit (draw) text to surface
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2), (display_height / 2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


##

def score(score):
    text = smallfont.render("Score: " + str(score), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [0, 0])


def randAppleGen():  # Function to generate random apples
    randAppleX = round(
        random.randrange(0, display_width - appleThickness))  # /10.0)*10.0 ##Create another rand X value for new apple
    randAppleY = round(
        random.randrange(0, display_height - appleThickness))  # /10.0)*10.0 ##Create another rand Y value for new apple
    return randAppleX, randAppleY


def gameIntro():  # Function for game menu.
    intro = True

    while intro:  # Event handling during menu
        for eachEvent in pygame.event.get():
            if eachEvent.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if eachEvent.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if eachEvent.key == pygame.K_c:
                    gameLoop()
                if eachEvent.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        # Text displayed in menu
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to Slither",
                          green,
                          -90,
                          "large")

        message_to_screen("The more apples you eat, the longer you are",
                          black,
                          100)

        message_to_screen("The objective of the game is to eat red apples",
                          black,
                          0,
                          "small")

        message_to_screen("If you run into yourself, or the edges, you die!",
                          black,
                          30,
                          "small")
        message_to_screen("Press C to play or Q to quit.",
                          black,
                          180)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(500)


def snake(blockSize, snakeList):  # Function to draw snake

    if direction == "right":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeHeadImg,
                                       270)  # In gameLoop, right,left,up,down are used to change direction of snakeHead
    elif direction == "left":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeHeadImg, 90)
    elif direction == "up":
        head = snakeHeadImg
    elif direction == "down":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeHeadImg, 180)

    gameDisplay.blit(head, (snakeList[-1][0], snakeList[-1][1]))  ##???
    for XandY in snakeList[:-1]:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green,
                         [XandY[0], XandY[1], blockSize, blockSize])  ##width height, width height, drawing


##Main Game Loop

def gameLoop():
    global direction  ## Make direction a global var. Important

    # Local variables
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width / 2
    lead_y = display_height / 2

    lead_x_change = 10
    lead_y_change = 0

    snakeList = []
    snakeLength = 3



    randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()  # Generate apples. Calls randAppleGen()

    # Main Game Loop ##eventHandler
    while not gameExit:
        snakeHead = []  # Creates list snakeHead
        snakeHead.append(lead_x)  # Appends snakeHead x value to list
        snakeHead.append(lead_y)  # Appends snakeHead y value to list
        snakeList.append(snakeHead)  # Appends coordinates of snakeHead x,y to list
        while gameOver == True:  # Handles game over
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              red,
                              -50,
                              size="large")

            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit",
                              black,
                              50,
                              size="medium")

            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():  # eventHandler for loss screen
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        direction = "right"
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():  # eventHandler for keyboard events during game
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:  # Each of these handles either arrow keys or WASD key events.
                    lead_x_change = -blockSize
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    direction = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    lead_x_change = blockSize
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    direction = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    lead_y_change = -blockSize
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    direction = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    lead_y_change = blockSize
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    direction = "down"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pauseGame()

        # Checks if user has hit screen boundaries.

        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:  # If user hits display boundaries
            gameOver = True  # They lose

        lead_x += lead_x_change  # Ensures continous movement of the snake
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        # Drawing

        gameDisplay.fill(bground)  # Fills the display background with predefined bground colour (defined at the top)

        gameDisplay.blit(appleImg,
                         (randAppleX, randAppleY))  ##Draws the apple using the appleImg, at random coordinates.





        if len(
                snakeList) > snakeLength:  # If the length of the list of snake body coordinates is greater than the length
            del snakeList[0]  # Delete the oldest value in the list (as the snake is constantly moving)

        for eachSegment in snakeList[:-1]:  # For each coordinate in snakeList
            if eachSegment == snakeHead:  # If the segment touches the snakeHead
                ##                gameDisplay.fill(bground)
                ##                snake(blockSize, snakeList)
                ##
                ##                pygame.display.update
                time.sleep(0.3)
                gameOver = True  # Game over

        snake(blockSize, snakeList)  ##Creates snake using function snake

        score(snakeLength - 3)  # Displays score (it minuses 3 because the snake starts at 3)

        pygame.display.update()  ##Updates to screen


        ## COLLISION DETECTION 

        if lead_x + blockSize > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleX + appleThickness:
            if lead_y + blockSize > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + appleThickness:
                randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                snakeLength += 1

        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

    ##update screen


##
gameIntro()
gameLoop()
##Code goes above.
```

I have a problem where if my snake is going right, and then it turns left, my snake will crash onto itself and the game will end.

I want to design this so when my snake is going right, it cannot simply turn left, crash into itself and end the game. So when it turns right, it can only turn up, down, or keep going right. So simply, I want to make it so it cannot run backwards into itself.

I have tried coding this in myself, and I have tried many methods but nothing has worked.

Please help!!

Comment: You have to exclude the 'opposite' direction in your event handling in some way. One simple way would be to add another condition to your key check, something like `if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a and direction != "right":` for each of the four directions.

Comment: instead of `for XandY in snakeList[:-1]:` you can do `for X, Y in snakeList[:-1]:` and then you can use `[X, Y, blockSize, blockSize]` instead of `[XandY[0], XandY[1], blockSize, blockSize]` - it will be more readable.

Comment: @ThomasKühn why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @willlplaya please always try to reduce your code to the [minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you post it here. I also recommend posting your game on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pygame to get some refactoring tips. On the codereview site you have to post all of your code instead of a minimal example. And good job so far!

Comment: @skrx I now posted an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Without altering your code too much (and without testing), an easy way to get what you want is to add another condition to your key checks. If you alter the relevant code section as follows, all should be fine:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # eventHandler for keyboard events during game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a) and direction != "right":  # Each of these handles either arrow keys or WASD key events.
                lead_x_change = -blockSize
                lead_y_change = 0
                direction = "left"
            elif (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d) and direction != "left":
                lead_x_change = blockSize
                lead_y_change = 0
                direction = "right"
            elif (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w) and direction != "down":
                lead_y_change = -blockSize
                lead_x_change = 0
                direction = "up"
            elif (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s) and direction != "up":
                lead_y_change = blockSize
                lead_x_change = 0
                direction = "down"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pauseGame()
```

Mind the parentheses around the `or`'d key checks!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!  - This is my first project outside of small generic problem solving questions using basic python, when I saw your solution I almost hit myself from not being able to think of this earlier. How do you suggest I further improve simple problem solving skills to not only get better at python but programming in general?

Comment: I think the suggestion by @skrx to post your code on codereview is quite a good one. Apart from that, just keep programming. The skills come with the experience. Every now and then, have a look at the code you have written and spend some time thinking how to improve it. Oh, and reading questions and answers on StackOverflow helps a lot -- that's why I'm around :)

Comment: Heard good things about this community and people like you definitely make it so! I'll be sure to continue programming - I'm 15, so still got a long way to go, but the start is feeling good. I've covered all the basics and whatnot, but I don't want to continue learning basics, I want to apply myself to projects. Do you recommend for me to apply my basics with projects and develop with them or go back to the theory side of things (online courses, books, etc)

Comment: @willlplaya Courses and theory can only get you that far, so at least I would go with programming own things. Just remember to also read from time to time :)